# Pandas Keyerror after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, keyerror

I want to filter a dataframe after having done a group by on it but am getting a keyerror, here is some example code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
                [0, 1, 'm', 5.0], [0, 1, 'm', -7.0],[0, 1, 'm', 9.0],[0, 1, 'm', 32.0],[0, 1, 'm', -11.0],
                [0, 6, 'm', -12.0], [0, 6, 'm', 15.0],[0, 6, 'm', -16.0],[0, 6, 'm', -3.0],[0, 6, 'm', 21.0],
                [0, 12, 'm', 15.0], [0, 12, 'm', 51.0],[0, 12, 'm', 4.0],[0, 12, 'm', 3.0],[0, 12, 'm', 1.0],
                [1, 1, 'm', 5.0], [1, 1, 'm', -7.0],[1, 1, 'm', 9.0],[1, 1, 'm', 32.0],[1, 1, 'm', -11.0],
                [1, 6, 'm', -12.0], [1, 6, 'm', 15.0],[1, 6, 'm', -16.0],[1, 6, 'm', -3.0],[1, 6, 'm', 21.0],
                [1, 12, 'm', 15.0], [1, 12, 'm', 51.0],[1, 12, 'm', 4.0],[1, 12, 'm', 3.0],[1, 12, 'm', 1.0]
                ],
                columns=['id', 'timeperiod', 'timeperiodtype', 'value'])
df['good'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x>0 else 0)
print(df)
print(df[df['timeperiod']>6])

df = df[['id', 'timeperiod','timeperiodtype','good']][df['timeperiod']>0].groupby(['id','timeperiod','timeperiodtype']).mean()

print(df[df['timeperiod']>6])
```

I want to avoid using reset_index as in the final code I will have several dataframes of similar shape that I will be aggregating/merging/concatenating.

I am sure I must be missing something obvious.

How can I use the column names to filter the grouped dataframe?

Comment: can you post full error message as well?

Comment: Your last print command doesn't work because the column named "timeperiod" is an index after the `.groupby()` command. Try `print(df)` instead `print(df[df['timeperiod']>6])` and everything is fine.

Comment: @mosc9575 - print(df) will not filter the results.

Comment: Please try `print(df.query('timeperiod > 6'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by condition and by columns names and then for avoid `MultiIndex` add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) or parameter `as_index=False`:

```
df = df.loc[df['timeperiod']>0, ['id', 'timeperiod','timeperiodtype','good']].groupby(['id','timeperiod','timeperiodtype']).mean().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df = df.loc[df['timeperiod']>0, ['id', 'timeperiod','timeperiodtype','good']].groupby(['id','timeperiod','timeperiodtype'], as_index=False).mean()
```

---

```
print(df)
   id  timeperiod timeperiodtype  good
0   0           1              m   0.6
1   0           6              m   0.4
2   0          12              m   1.0
3   1           1              m   0.6
4   1           6              m   0.4
5   1          12              m   1.0

print(df[df['timeperiod']>6])
   id  timeperiod timeperiodtype  good
2   0          12              m   1.0
5   1          12              m   1.0
```

EDIT:

For filter in `MuiltiIndex` is possible use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
df = df.loc[df['timeperiod']>0, ['id', 'timeperiod','timeperiodtype','good']].groupby(['id','timeperiod','timeperiodtype']).mean()
print(df)
                              good
id timeperiod timeperiodtype      
0  1          m                0.6
   6          m                0.4
   12         m                1.0
1  1          m                0.6
   6          m                0.4
   12         m                1.0
   
print(df[df.index.get_level_values('timeperiod')>6])
                              good
id timeperiod timeperiodtype      
0  12         m                1.0
1  12         m                1.0
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid reset_index and keep this format. I would like to know if it is possible to filter the dataframe that results from my groupby, not how to reshape my dataframe.

Comment: @Giles - Sorry, I dont understand it, answer was edited.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer a thousand times. Because get_group() is deprecated and for some reason nothing else I tried work, I spent hours on a goose chase trying to select a row from a grouped DF. `as_index=False` was the key here. Thank you so much.